# Possible chrome 45 bug with css custom cursor?

Tags: css, google-chrome, cursor

when there are a **not cached images** 
the css rule: `cursor:url(smiley.gif),auto;` don't work property on chrome 45.
for example:
open this link with an anonymous chrome session https://jsfiddle.net/6k7otufq/7/ 
move your mouse hover the div... and don't move your cursor... as you shown  in the first cycle (A...Z) the cursor won't be synchronize with bottom image... but if you move it or wait for the second cycle it works like a charms.
on Firefox, Safari, Opera works...

There is a code workaround? 
 In my real case there is a server that generates a random new image every N second. (so it will not be cached)

Comment: A new version was released 45.0.2454.93 m. I've opened your jsfiddle and everything is looking good. Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: @typo_78 open jsfiddle with incognito mode... here on mac with 45.0.2454.93 (64-bit) still remain bug...

Comment: very true, same here on Win7 64-bit. sorry

Comment: @typo_78 here the bugs can you star it? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532233&thanks=532233&ts=1442355306

Comment: Done! can you star mine too? :) https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=530258